# Trying to create a sub-menu for a horizontal menu inside a grid

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-grid

I am trying to create a horizontal menu with submenu in a grid. It prints the children in the parent's line and move the parent list above the main menu.

```css
.hmenu {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 9;
  background-color: #015491;
  margin-top: 5px
}

.hmenu ul {
  text-align: center
}

.hmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.hmenu a {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 300%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.hmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #73b3e7
}

.hmenu > li > ul {
  top: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="hmenu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</li>
  <li><a href="#">Main</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Main Submenu-1</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Tech</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Launguages</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question or problem?

Comment: Have you tried following this structure? https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/build-a-dropdown-menu-in-css-grid/

Comment: I’m trying to create a nested list with grid

Comment: @user6642297 Can you provide an exact picture of output? So we can understand well.

Comment: Trying to create a drop down menu inside a grid.